# Bloquear el uso de una clase mientras se actualiza

Tags: java, spring-boot, multitasking

Actualmente estoy con una duda que aun no he podido resolver.

Tengo actualmente un bean de configuracion como se observa a continuacion

```
@Bean
Api api () throws Auth0Exception {
    API api = new Api(dominio, token);
    return api;
}
```

Esta se configura correctamente y no tengo hasta ahi ningun inconveniente, usamos la clase API para realizar algunas peticiones, como pueden ver existe una variable token esta se usa para realizar las peticiones, hay un proceso que se realiza para actualizar ese token antes de que expire, pero durante el proceso de actualizacion del API con el nuevo token debemos asegurarnos que no existan peticiones. es decir que el objeto API se bloquee mientras se termina de actualizar el proceso de actualizacion del token.

Intente realizar un wrapper para que al momento de llamar API se ejecuta un metodo getter con la palabra reservada synchronized pero se que esa a pesar de que puede solucionar el problema no es una practica hoy en dia recomendada.

```
public class ApiWrapper {
private final API api;

ApiWrapper api () throws Auth0Exception {
API api = new Api(dominio, token);
this.api = api}

public synchronized APIgetApi() {
    return api;
}
```

Por lo cual agradezo cualquier informacion o recomendacion que me puedan brindar para poderlo implementar gracias por adelantado!!!

Comment: Sincronizar un simple getter no va a hacer nada respecto a los objetos que estén usando la instancia de tu api. Lo único que estás evitando es dos llamados al mismo tiempo de ese get, pero poco más. Desafortunadamente, tu problema no queda muy claro y sería necesario conocer como tal la implementación de la clase api y como la usas para poder ayudarte.

Comment: la implementacion de la clase no es creada por nosotros es de la libreria de auth0 https://github.com/auth0/auth0-java pero el punto de entrada lo hacemos con un getter y eso ha funcionado solo que por buenas practicas queremos evitar en lo posible la palabra synchronized